# Collection with duplicate IDs flatten to one row

Tags: c#

I have a collection the problem is I am trying to flatten it to one row.

```
Example
ID      name         description  name2      Description2
555     newname      a descript
555                               name2      Description2name
543     onename      myname
```

results what should it look like.

```
Example final
ID      name         description  name2      Description2
555     newname      a descript   name2      Description2name 
543     onename      myname
```

Basically using a linq statement then `list.Add(addlist)`
Once the list has been added to my DTO then I use foreach loop.
Not to sure how the final should come together to produce the final results like example above.

Comment: What happens when same column for a given ID, has values in more than 1 row or is it guaranteed to not have one, only one row will have value for a given column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how well this performs but it does the trick :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dataItems = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data { ID = 555, Name = "newname", Description = "a descript" },
            new Data { ID = 555, Name2 = "name2", Description2 = "Description2name" },
            new Data { ID = 543, Name = "onename", Description = "myname" },
        };

        var aggregate = dataItems
            .GroupBy(x => x.ID, x => x)
            .Select(g => g.Aggregate((current, next) =>
            {
                current.Description = current.Description ?? next.Description;
                current.Description2 = current.Description2 ?? next.Description2;
                current.Name = current.Name ?? next.Name;
                current.Name2 = current.Name2 ?? next.Name2;
                return current;
            }));

        foreach (var item in aggregate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID}\t{item.Name}\t{item.Description}\t{item.Name2}\t{item.Description2}");
        }
    }
}


public sealed class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Description2 { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is to group by the `ID`, then for each group, create an aggregate of all the items of the group and just fill in the members as you go through each object that has that data.

Comment: note that Aggregate modifies the first item of the collection is working on: in this case dataItems [0] will be different at the end of the method compared from the start.Possibly an unexpected outcome

Answer (score 1):

Just extending @joseph-serido answer, I would create a method for "transform" a group of `Data` having the same key into a single `Data` instance.

Something like that:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static Data GetDataFromGroup(IGrouping<int, Data> dataGroup)
    {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.ID = dataGroup.Key;
        data.Description = dataGroup.Select(d => d.Description).FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))?? string.Empty;
        data.Description2 = dataGroup.Select(d => d.Description2).FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))?? string.Empty;
        data.Name = dataGroup.Select(d => d.Name).FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))?? string.Empty;
        data.Name2 = dataGroup.Select(d => d.Name2).FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))?? string.Empty;
        return data;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var dataItems = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data { ID = 555, Name = "newname", Description = "a descript" },
            new Data { ID = 555, Name2 = "name2", Description2 = "Description2name" },
            new Data { ID = 543, Name = "onename", Description = "myname" },
        };

        var computedData = dataItems
            .GroupBy(x => x.ID, x => x)
            .Select(g => GetDataFromGroup(g));

        foreach (var item in computedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID}\t{item.Name}\t{item.Description}\t{item.Name2}\t{item.Description2}");
        }   
    }
}


public sealed class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Description2 { get; set; }
}
```

See it [there](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LfcgJJ) giving the same result as Joseph code

I think you have 2 advantages:

- more efficent since for each property it stops ciclying after the
  first non empty entry, using `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Aggregate`; but really, you will not get any noticeable
  difference as long as number of data is not big enough.
- more flexible: within the method you can insert more complicated logic (e.g. what happens if "Description" has a valid value in more than one element? Take the first one? concatenate them? anything else?)

In general, I think using Linq facilities is good as long as it makes the code more readable. 
In this case, I think the translation from a group to a single item worth a separate method

Comment: Fun tip, you can also change `.Select(g => GetDataFromGroup(g))` to `.Select(GetDataFromGroup)` :)